# regression analysis in questionnaire

Tags: regression, logistic, binomial-distribution, survey

I am performing both descriptive analysis and a logistic regression on a  questionnaire`s data that I have sampled regarding Fibromyalgia.

Data consists of symptoms that are dependent dichotomous variables, disability that are dependent ordinal variables and physical activity that are independent and numerical variables(data is number of times exercised) + binominal(walk=yes/no swim=yes/no physio=yes/no)

- What kind of analyses are the best to investigate the symptoms to the full?
- Are there any possibilities to make logistic regression and put results together in a large table?
- Basically, does physical exercise affect symptoms and disability?

Thanks

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  How can symptoms or disability be a dependent variable?  The analysis you propose would posit that people have disability *because*  of their exercise habits. 

If you want to see if exercise affects symptoms, you're going to need a lot more data - probably longitudinal data - and, even then, causation is likely to go both ways.

Answer (score 1):

1) You might want to try a chi-square test to figure out whether symptoms A and B are equally present in cases where physical activity follows a specific pattern, say (Walk=yes&Swim=no&Physio=yes). Do this for all frequent patterns of physical activity and then focus your analyses on those patterns that **affect the symptoms differently**.

2) You could perform **linear regression for each of ordinal disability variables**, using numeric combinations of physical activity flag and physical activity measure as predictors. Your predictors should look like (Walk=yes|no)*(Number of times exercised: Walk) ; they can take positive or zero values.

3) The same combined factors could be used as predictors in **logistic regression for each pattern of symptoms**. I'd suggest not wasting your data on predicting events like (SymptomA=yes); rather identify frequent patterns of symptoms (or patterns of medical interest) and model events like (SymptomA=yes&SymptomB=yes).